# Can't Use Classes From App.css In Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styling

I'm having an issue with this specific project where I cannot use a style class defined in "src/App.css" for a component in "src/components/layout/Header.js".

This is strange because I have another project that I use for notes and references where this works properly..

I'm being given the error:

> The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

src/App.css snippet:

```
.header-dock{
    width:100%;
    z-index:3
}
```

src/components/layout/Header.js snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div className='header-dock'></div>);
    }
}
```

Header tag is then added to the App.js return statement, and is in-turn rendered to the DOM on index.js.

Comment: try to comment out all the other components in App.js , and leave only the header :) because I think the problem is not at the header, if it still doesn't work make  a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/fork/react I will support you after you send your link

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return <div className='header-dock'></div>;
```

into

```
 return <div class='header-dock'></div>;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for reaching out. I just tried this one. Unfortunately, the same error is given for the same lines of code inside the component after making this change.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, you need to import the CSS into your component file.

```
import './App.css'
```

This is assuming the component and CSS files are in the same folder.

EDIT:

The issue was a stray style prop in the component. After adding brackets `style={{margin: '10px'}}`, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Hello, The App.css file is already imported in the App.js file, which are both in the same directory. The Header component is then added to the App, like I've seen in other examples. Even importing the CSS file on the Header component class itself does not fix the error, unfortunately.

Comment: That seems odd. Have you tried putting the styles in the top level `index.css` file? That might work but it seems weird that importing the styles directly doesn't work.

Comment: I've just tried using index.css and the same issue is given. I'm probably just going to delete this project and recreate a new one and start over because this definitely works in 2 more of my projects at the moment. create-react-app is total garbage.

Comment: Is there a stray `style` prop in your App.js file or another file? I'm not entirely sure it has anything to do with the CSS file. If you accidentally used `style` instead of `className` then I think that might be the issue.

Comment: This is the issue. I DID have 1 style prop hiding deep in the markup.. After changing it from style="margin: 10px" to style={{margin: '10px'}} the issue has resolved itself. Thank you so very much for your patience... I had not paid enough attention when converting this from a static site to React.... It is strange because the error gives no mention of style tag syntax. It only wants to tell me that React classes take objects instead of string names...

Comment: It took me a minute to realize what the error was talking about haha. Glad you got it figured out.